# mysql report from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, report

This question I got from PHP mysql interview test. I want to know what is the best solution to create following reports. It looks simple but something with it.

Here is the image of two reports I want please visit:
[image of two reports](http://test.lankaven.com/test/Qimage.png)

Sorry for the link because I'm new to Stack Overflow so I can't upload images.

Here is the mysql dump file if you want,
[exam.sql file](http://test.lankaven.com/test/exam.sql)

Yes there is a home work, I created these two reports, but I'm not quite sure is that the best way. I didn't post my effort because I hope fresh idea. Here are their points (on my interview )

Conditions:

- You must create these TWO reports dynamicaly.
- You can create only ONE PHP script for these two reports.

Comment: sounds a lot like homework.... any effort on your part yet?

Comment: you need to use sql join statements to join the tables on common attributes. something like `select * from t_marks AS m JOIN t_users as u ON m.user_id = u.user_id`

Comment: yes there is a home work,I created this two reports, but i'm not quite sure is that the best way.i didn't post my effort coz i hope fresh idea. here is there points(on my interview )

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the MySQL [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) query to get the tables joined up in this way. Furthermore, for the second table, you need to use a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier on top of that JOIN. The manual in the links should explain it all.

Comment: I created this two reports, but i'm not quite sure is that the best way.i didn't post my effort coz i hope fresh idea. here is there points(on my interview )my main problem is not mysql query how to fetch results in to column and the same rows can you do it from single query and while clause???

Comment: No, you do it with a JOIN. Or, excuse my French, RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about MySQL Joins.
[MySQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

SELECT t1.user_fname AS FName, t1.user_lname AS LName, t2.subject AS Subject, t2.marks AS Marks
FROM t_users AS t1
JOIN t_marks AS t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id;

For Report A.

SELECT t1.user_fname AS FName, t1.user_lname AS LName, t2.subject AS Subject, SUM(t2.subject) AS Total
FROM t_users AS t1
JOIN t_marks AS t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY (t2.subject);

For Report B, I suppose it should work.

Comment: I created this two reports, but i'm not quite sure is that the best way.i didn't post my effort coz i hope fresh idea. here is there points(on my interview )my main problem is not mysql query how to fetch results in to column and the same rows can you do it from single query and while clause???